# Extract Android Image from Samsung Galaxy S4 device

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-s-4, odin

I'm quite happy flashing stock versions of Samsung Android to my Samsung Galaxy S4.

What I'd like to do is install some apps on my phone and then extract the phone into an image that I can flash back to say another S4.

Is this possible?  I have been using Odin to flash the device so far.

Comment: If both devices are identical, that could be accomplished via [Nandroid](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info). But as you're speaking about *stock* versions, it probably won't work for you – unless you're using at least a [custom recovery](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info).

Comment: Our current approach is to load up a stock image using Odin, then use ADB to automate the installation of some apps, rooting, tweaking and unrooting.

Comment: Yes, I've understood that. There are ways to *upload* images to a device that way. But AFAIK no way to *download* – except for the mentioned Nandroid images.

Answer (score 0):

Go to recovery and create backup or use titanium back up to back up apps. One more way is to recompile rom zip with placing needed apk in installation folder. You can find more details on xda forums